# WebAPI DELETE request return 404 error in Azure

Tags: azure, asp.net-web-api, iis-8

I have been trying to get the DELETE requests in my ASP.net WebAPI(ASP.net web role) working on Azure and locally on my machine.But end up getting "not found" error.

I have following configuration for the web.config of the ASP.net WebAPI web role:

```
<system.webServer>
  <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
  <modules>
    <remove name="WebDAVModule" />
  </modules>
  <handlers>
   <remove name="WebDAV" />
   <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" />
   <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" />
   <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
   <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit"
     path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS"
     modules="IsapiModule"
     scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll"
     preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32"
     responseBufferLimit="0" />
   <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit"
     path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS"
     modules="IsapiModule"
     scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll"
     preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64"
     responseBufferLimit="0" />
   <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0"
     path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS"
     type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler"
     preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
 </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

For making it work on IISExpress, I changed the $:\Users\\Documents\IISExpress\config\applicationhost.config configuration and commented out the WebDav portions of it and added the "PUT,DELETE" verbs appropriately.

To test my WebAPI I created a simple windows forms (.net 4.5 ) c# application and used the httpclient as below:

```
const string key = "user1";
var client = new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri("http://abcd.cloudapp.net/") };
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
    new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
var requestUrl = string.Format("api/user/{0}", key);
var deleteAsync = client.DeleteAsync(requestUrl).Result;
```

The response I get it following:

```
{StatusCode: 404,
  ReasonPhrase: 'Not Found',
  Version: 1.1,
  Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent,
  Headers:
  {
    Pragma: no-cache
    Cache-Control: no-cache
    Date: Fri, 12 Apr 2013 06:40:31 GMT
    Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
    X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
    X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
    Content-Length: 128
    Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
    Expires: -1
}}  System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage
```

How do I get it to work on Azure? and possibly on my local machine as well.

Comment: Have you tried adding a "Get" action in order to test the route? does this work correctly on the Visual Studio Web Server?

Comment: @amhed
Actually... GET,POST work fine. Its just the DELETE verb which isnt working.

I have changed the IIS 8 express configuration to add this verb but when debugging, the IIS Express server which starts up, picks up a configuration where the DELETE verb is missing.

I have mentioned more details with screenshots here:
[link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsazuredevelopment/thread/8906fd7e-a60b-484e-be63-9574b9fca44a/)

Comment: Did you find the answer? My experience of using PUT and DELETE specifically with IIS is that you have to disable or uninstall Web DAV for these HTTP methods to work correctly.

Comment: @OliGray Yeah, I tried uninstalling Web DAV as well. But somehow it didn't work. I finally worked my way around the issue. I got no luck from the MSDN forums either ... [MSDN](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsazuredevelopment/thread/8906fd7e-a60b-484e-be63-9574b9fca44a/)

Comment: I’m getting this on PUT requests in an Azure WebSite - was there ever a solution?